# using dollar sign ($) as a password on ios7 simulator

Tags: ios7, passwords, ios-simulator

I've got stucked inputting a password account (in this case twitter and facebook) in ios 7.03 simulator setting. Its keep Appearing an alert that my account is wrong. Then, I tried on safari (safari in simulator) to input a similar account, and the result is same. But, if I tried to login in web, not in simulator, its hasn't a problem in my account.

I tried again, but this one I tried on ios 6.0 and 6.1 simulator, then the result is, I can login, through setting or in webview on safari. Is it a kind of issue in ios7 simulator or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a little research and the answer is, ios 7 simulator is not accept a dollar sign as a password input. Just dollar sign, the other character like pound(!), at(@), hash(#) and kind of that character is allowed to be a password input. I dont know why the reason ios 7 and ios 6 had a little different with this, but maybe apple had some good reason about security factor.

Comment: Do you have any sources? Or you mean you just personally tried those different symbols?

Comment: Thats based on my experience, I haven't try different symbols yet.

Comment: There's an app with a login form. The first time I launch the app, I can't use a dollar sign in the password field. But if I log in and then back out, if I then try to use the dollar sign in the password field, it works. It seems it doesn't work only on the initial load of the field, perhaps.

Comment: On my machine it is only through my Mac keyboard that I cannot type a dollar sign. If you use the on-screen keyboard it works as expected.

Comment: 2019 and I have ran into this on the current iOS 12 simulators!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the $ symbol to clipboard and then paste into the password field. But you can't use paste from the Edit menu. You have to right click in the password field and paste that way. #bugs